# torch transform.resize() vs cv2.resize()

Tags: python, pytorch

The CNN model takes an image tensor of size `(112x112)` as input and gives  `(1x512)` size tensor as output.

Using Opencv function `cv2.resize()` or using `Transform.resize` in pytorch to resize the input to `(112x112)` gives different outputs.

What's the reason for this? (I understand that the difference in the underlying implementation of opencv resizing vs torch resizing might be a cause for this, But I'd like to have a detailed understanding of it)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
from PIL import image
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms as trans


# device for pytorch
device = torch.device('cuda:0')

torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')

model = torch.jit.load("traced_facelearner_model_new.pt")
model.eval()

# read the example image used for tracing
image=cv2.imread("videos/example.jpg")

test_transform = trans.Compose([
            trans.ToTensor(),
            trans.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
        ])   
test_transform2 = trans.Compose([
            trans.Resize([int(112), int(112)]),
            trans.ToTensor(),
            trans.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
        ])      

resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (112, 112))

tensor1 = test_transform(resized_image).to(device).unsqueeze(0)
tensor2 = test_transform2(Image.fromarray(image)).to(device).unsqueeze(0)
output1 = model(tensor1)
output2 = model(tensor2)
```

The output1 and output2 tensors have different values.

Answer (score 4):

Basically `torchvision.transforms.Resize()` uses `PIL.Image.BILINEAR` interpolation by default.

While in your code you simply use `cv2.resize` which doesn't use any interpolation.

For example

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

a = cv2.imread('videos/example.jpg')
b = cv2.resize(a, (112, 112))
c = np.array(Image.fromarray(a).resize((112, 112), Image.BILINEAR))
```

You will see that `b` and `c` are slightly different.

## Edit:

Actually the opencv docs says

> INTER_LINEAR - a bilinear interpolation (used by default)

But yeah, it doesn't give  the same result as `PIL`.

## Edit 2:

This also in the docs

> To shrink an image, it will generally look best with INTER_AREA interpolation

And apparently

```
d = cv2.resize(a, (112, 112), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Gives almost the same result as `c`. But these don't answer the question unfortunately.

Comment: OpenCV by default uses No interpolation

Comment: Read here https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d

Comment: It takes `None` in Python but by default `cv::resize` uses `INTER_LINEAR`

Comment: @Natthaphon Hongcharoen. PIL applies some **anti-aliasing** filter before resizing. But not cv2 this also leads to some differences

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen here we are talking about Python not C++

Comment: @Imran In case you don't know, opencv runs in C++ no matter where you excute it (Python, JAVA, C# etc.).

Comment: @Imran This is very important as so many people have a misconception of, things run in Python always stay in Python and thus it will slow, which is far away from reality as pretty much every single libraries that slow to run (Tensorflow, Pytorch, Numpy) are all run in C/C++ (and sometimes Fortran) and they aren't much slower than pure C++.

Comment: @GirishDattatrayHegde That's answered the question. I think you should make that as another answer as it can be easily overlooked here.